# Trying to work out mongoose relationship coding for REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is a stupid question but I have tried to wrap my head around this via Google, code snippits, tutorials, and all of them lead me to examples in which the models are too shallow for the coding I want to do.

I have an app I want to develop where data is in the form of parents and children:-
- Organisation
- Projects that belong to those organisations
- Releases that belong to those projects

and so on, but I don't fully understand how I can write a route in express that follows said hierachy and I come from an SQL relational background. Do I use cookies, or part of the route? I know how to set up the model, from what I understand, using:

```
var organisationSchema = ({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    description: String,
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

for Organisation and

```
var projectSchema = ({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
}
```

for project but then how do I set up my post route to add the project to the correct organisation

```
router.route('/api/project')
    .post(function(req, res){
        project = new Project();
        project.name = req.body.name;
        project.organisation = req.body.organisation;    
            if (err)
                res.send(err);


        })

        project.save(function(err){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Project ' + project.name + ' created.'});
        })
    })
```

Do I need a cookie to populate the organisation in this example?

Answer (score 1):

If your projects belong to organizations, you'll either want to include an array of objectIds in your organization schema which will contain project IDs or a field in your project schema that will contain the relevant organization ID.

You can send the proper organization either in the body, as you are, or in the URL parameters.

For example, something similar to this:

```
router.route('/api/:organizationId/project')
    .post(function(req, res, next) {
        var project = new Project({
            name: req.body.name,
            organization: req.params.organizationId
        });

        if(err) { return next(err); }

        project.save(function(err, savedProject) {
            if(err) { return next(err); }

            return res.status(200).json({ message: "Project " + savedProject.name + " created." });
        }
    }
```

If you pay attention to the communication/messaging model and routes in this repository, it might help: https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter/tree/master/server

Comment: That works great, now the next thing I am trying to get working is the adding of that project in to the organisation. I'm still getting my head around best-practices here but I think for my context I'd be wanting to save projects within organisations since they are one organisation to many project relationships. Would it be a matter of finding by ID and adding the new project ID to the projects array of the organisation?